How to get list of Ready Node in a AKS Cluster
My Requirement is to fetch the number of Ready Nodes in AKS Cluster.
currently if i run the command on Azure Portal under "Run Command" section i get output in this format
aniket@abcd.com> kubectl get nodes 
NAME   STATUS   ROLES   AGE    VERSION
is there any command or api which i can use? I have tried the below command which didn't work
kubectl get nodes -o json|jq -r '.items[]|select(.status.conditions[].type=="Ready")|select(.spec.taints|not).metadata.name' | wc -l 

kubectl get nodes --no-headers | grep -c 'Ready'

kubectl get nodes --no-headers | awk '$2 == "Ready" && !($3 ~ /taint/) { count++ } END { print count }'

I'm not able to use grep,js,awk etc as it is not available also i'm trying to avoid the ugly logic i have to write in case i take the output in json format,

Kubernetes has a very rich HTTP API and SDKs in many languages, so if you're having trouble with shell pipelines or JSONPath syntax, writing a proper program can be a choice.

For example:
kubectl get nodes -o jsonpath='{.items[*].status.conditions[?(@.type=="Ready" && @.status=="True")].status}'

Here you can read a little bit more about jsonpath support in kubectl

aniket@abcd.com> kubectl get nodes -o jsonpath='{.items[*].status.conditions[?(@.type=="Ready" && @.status=="True")].status}'
error: error parsing jsonpath {.items[*].status.conditions[?(@.type=="Ready" && @.status=="True")].status}, unrecognized character in action: U+0026 '&'

I'm getting the above error
